# Are my Android issues and this repeating debug log related?

Tags: usb-debugging, bugs

I've been having many issues on my Pixel:

- takes 10+ seconds to wake up
- answering / making a call will freeze the phone app, or cause the phone to reset
- cannot train "ok google" voice model

When I use USB debugging to see what my idle phone is doing, I see a constant stream of the following messages looped. So I'm getting the same warnings and failures multiple times every second. It looks like audio issues. Is this related?

```
03-14 16:32:14.149 607-647/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Warning: Resource [2, 0] not supported for core 1. Instead use resource for core 0
03-14 16:32:14.149 607-647/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [2, 2, 0]
03-14 16:32:14.155 7252-14632/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(8) apply and update mixer path: audio-record
03-14 16:32:14.685 7252-14632/? E/audio_hw_primary: start_input_stream: pcm_prepare returned -1
03-14 16:32:14.696 7252-14632/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(8) reset and update mixer path: audio-record
03-14 16:32:14.696 7252-14632/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = voice-rec-mic
03-14 16:32:14.696 7252-14632/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(63: voice-rec-mic)
03-14 16:32:14.702 7252-14632/? D/sound_trigger_platform: platform_stdev_check_and_update_concurrency: concurrency active 0, tx 0, rx 0, concurrency session_allowed 1
03-14 16:32:14.702 7252-14632/? W/audio_hw_primary: start_input_stream: exit: status(-1)
03-14 16:32:14.723 7252-14632/? I/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB AFE returned = -19
03-14 16:32:14.723 7252-14632/? D/sound_trigger_platform: platform_stdev_check_and_update_concurrency: concurrency active 0, tx 1, rx 0, concurrency session_allowed 0
03-14 16:32:14.723 7252-14632/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = voice-rec-mic
03-14 16:32:14.723 7252-14632/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(63: voice-rec-mic)
03-14 16:32:14.727 607-647/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Warning: Resource [2, 0] not supported for core 1. Instead use resource for core 0
03-14 16:32:14.727 607-647/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Not sure, but that sounds like an issue I had a while ago (could not accept incoming calls as the phone app was freezing, releasing the freeze only as soon as the remote site hung up; also the phone rebooted once a day without apparent reason). So just a short request for clarification: are you using any custom ROM, or the "stock system"?

Comment: @izzy Stock. 7.1.1

Comment: OK, then it's almost certainly a different issue. In my case it was a CM-based custom ROM, and a kernel "adjustment" by the ROM-baker solved it. It being a Pixel in your case suggests it *might* be related to the hardware issue reported lately for some Pixels.